# Inverse search with Emacs/AucTeX and SumatraPDF [on Windows 10]

Tags: emacs, auctex, forward-inverse-search, sumatrapdf

I've been trying to use *Emacs/AucTeX* along with *SumatraPDF* to view my output. In particular, I would like to make the *forward and inverse search* work. I use Windows 10.

**Problem**

Every time I double click something in my pdf output, a new instance (or a new window) of Emacs opens. Once at least one instance has .tex file opened, the following instances give the following message:

> Warning: desktop file appears to be in use by PID 5132.
>   Using it may cause conflicts.  Use it anyway? (y or n)

Regardless of my decision (y/n), I get new instances of Emacs with my .tex file open after every subsequent double click in my pdf output file.

I believe I should be redirected to a proper place in an opened .tex file in Emacs instead.

**My current configuration**

Here's what I added to my .emacs:

```el
(setq TeX-PDF-mode t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-mode t)
(setq TeX-source-correlate-method 'synctex)
(setq TeX-view-program-list
'(("Sumatra PDF" ("\"C:/Program Files (x86)/SumatraPDF/SumatraPDF.exe\" -reuse-instance"
   (mode-io-correlate " -forward-search %b %n ") " %o"))))

(eval-after-load 'tex
 '(progn
   (assq-delete-all 'output-pdf TeX-view-program-selection)
   (add-to-list 'TeX-view-program-selection '(output-pdf "Sumatra PDF")))
```

My "Set inverse search" command in SumatraPDF:

```el
"C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Emacs 24.5\bin\runemacs.exe"  +%l "%f"
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Disclaimer: I am new to Emacs -- sorry if my question is trivial.

Comment: Set `(server-start)` in your init file and try this command in SumatraPDF:  ``"C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Emacs 24.5\bin\emacsclientw.exe" -n +%l "%f"``

Answer (score 2):

Arash's suggestion in the comment above has solved the problem for me.